# How do I prove that $\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}}-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}} \approx 1$

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, radicals, nested-radicals

How do I prove that

$$\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}}-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}} \approx 1$$

without using the calculator?

Comment: Some MathJax would be good

Comment: Is just doing some rough numerical calculations sufficient? 20 is about halfway between 16 and 25, so sqrt(20) is about 4.5. So $20\pm\sqrt{20}$ is about 15.5 and 24.5. These in turn have square roots of about (a little less than) 4 and 5. This leaves $\sqrt{25} - \sqrt{16} = 1$. The "little less than" is a half, but it shifts both roots over by a similar amount, so it mostly cancels out.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Could you please add (to your question) what tools you have available (linear approximation of the square root function...?), and if appropriate, any ideas you've tried and where you got stuck?

Comment: @AlexMeiburg:  I thnk that should be an answer.  Well done

Comment: for a rough estimate, ignore the innermost square root it will not change much

Comment: @AlexMeiburg Nice [+1]

Comment: Actually, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x}}}-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x-\sqrt{x}}} = 1$. It appears that $x=20$ is close enough to $\infty$...

Comment: What do you even mean by $\approx$??

Answer (score 13):

In general, it holds that $$\sqrt{n(n-1)+\sqrt{n(n-1)+\sqrt{n(n-1)}}}=n-\frac{1}{8n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)$$ and that $$\sqrt{n(n-1)-\sqrt{n(n-1)-\sqrt{n(n-1)}}}=(n-1)+\frac{1}{8n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\,$$ for all $n\geq 1$.  Hence, their difference is $$1-\frac1{4n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\,.$$  In particular, for $n=5$, the difference should be about $1-\dfrac1{100}=0.99$.  This is quite close to the actual value of $0.9872649...$.

> From $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{1}{2}x+O\left(x^2\right)$, we have $\sqrt{1-\frac1n}=1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$.  This means $$\sqrt{n(n-1)}=n\,\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}=n\,\Biggl(1-\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\Biggr)=n-\frac{1}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\,,$$ which can also be written as $$\sqrt{n(n-1)}=(n-1)+\frac{1}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\,.$$  Ergo, $$\begin{align}\sqrt{n(n-1)+\sqrt{n(n-1)}}&=\sqrt{n^2-\frac{1}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}&=&n\,\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)}\\&=n\,\Biggl(1-\frac{1}{4n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\Biggr)&=&n-\frac{1}{4n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\,.\end{align}$$  Similarly, $$\sqrt{n(n-1)-\sqrt{n(n-1)}}=(n-1)-\frac{1}{4n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\,.$$  Hence, $$\begin{align}\sqrt{n(n-1)+\sqrt{n(n-1)+\sqrt{n(n-1)}}}&=\sqrt{n^2-\frac{1}{4n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)}\\&=n\,\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)}\\&=n\,\Biggl(1-\frac{1}{8n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\Biggr)\\&=n-\frac{1}{8n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\,.\end{align}$$  Likewise, $$\sqrt{n(n-1)-\sqrt{n(n-1)-\sqrt{n(n-1)}}}=(n-1)+\frac{1}{8n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\,.$$  In fact, we can prove by induction on $k$ that $$f^+_k\big(n(n-1)\big)=n-\frac{1}{2^kn^{k-1}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^k}\right)$$ and $$f^-_k\big(n(n-1)\big)=(n-1)-\frac{(-1)^k}{2^kn^{k-1}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^k}\right)\,,$$ where $f^+_k(x):=\sqrt{x+f^+_{k-1}(x)}$ with $f^+_0(x):=0$ and $f^-_k(x):=\sqrt{x-f^-_{k-1}(x)}$ with $f^-_0(x):=0$ for all $x\geq 0$ and for each $k=1,2,3,\ldots$.

Comment: Nice, but can you give details how you got those expansions?

Answer (score 7):

Even without a calculator, you can do the numerics fairly easily. 20 is about halfway between 16 and 25, so $\sqrt{20} \approx 4.5$. So $20\pm\sqrt{20}$ is about 15.5 and 24.5, respectively. These in turn have square roots of about (a little less than) 4 and 5. This leaves $\sqrt{25}−\sqrt{16}\approx 1$. The "little less than" might contribute significant error on its own, but since it's similar sizes we can expect it to largely cancel out: $\sqrt{25-\epsilon} - \sqrt{16-\epsilon} \approx \sqrt{25} - \sqrt{16}$, since we can expect it shift each root over by a similar amount. Here $\epsilon = 1/2$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sqrt{16 + \delta}$ these errors do compound but they compound to only about .03 or so...

Comment: I'm not sure quite where you mean. But yes. The approximations are that $\epsilon$ is the same for both the 25 and 16 terms; and that the $\epsilon$ is small enough that its offsets mostly cancel. The first one contributes roughly 0.02 resulting error for each term, the second one contributes -0.01 resulting error.

Comment: But you *add* epsilon to 16 to get the expression and *subtract* epsilon from 25 to get the expression.  They *don't* cancel out.  They *compound*.  But it's very small compounding.  See $\sqrt {16} < \sqrt {20-...}$ but $\sqrt {25} > \sqrt {20+...} $.  So you should have written $\sqrt {25 -\epsilon} -\sqrt {16+\epsilin} $.

Comment: Sorry, I think we misunderstood each other about what $\epsilon$ was! Here, how about this: $\sqrt{20} = 4.5 + \delta$. Then $\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}} = \sqrt{15.5-\delta} = \sqrt{16-\epsilon-\delta}$. and$\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}} = \sqrt{25-\epsilon+\delta}$. These values are approximately 4 and 5, so we can expect $\sqrt{20+\dots} \approx 25$ and $\sqrt{20-\dots} \approx 16$. The $\delta$ error, which you're talking about, will separate them, but $\delta \approx 0.03$. The $\epsilon = 0.5$ but mostly cancels out since it has the same sign on either side of the subtraction.

Comment: Actually, what's interesting is that as 20 = 25*(4/5) and 20 = 16*(5/4).  $\sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20}}} = 4*\sqrt[8](5/4)$ and $\sqrt{20 +\sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20}}} = 5*\sqrt[8](4/5)$.

Answer (score 6):

If we consider an infinite chain.

Suppose $x = \sqrt{20 +\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}$

$x = \sqrt{20 +x}\\
x^2 = 20 + x\\
x^2 - x - 20 = 0\\
(x-5)(x+4) = 0$

$x$ must be greater than $0, x = 5$

and $y = \sqrt{20 -\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}$

$y = \sqrt{20 - y}\\
y^2 + y - 20=0\\
y = 4$

$x-y = 1$

As we add more terms under those square roots 
$\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}}-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}}$
converges toward 1.

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csqrt%7B20%2B%5Csqrt%7B20%2B%5Csqrt%7B20%7D%7D%7D-%5Csqrt%7B20-%5Csqrt%7B20-%5Csqrt%7B20%7D%7D%7D) gives $0.98\cdots$.

Comment: I missed a key in my calculation.. 0.98 is correct.

Comment: even if it converges the difference may be far from $1$ at this part of the iteration

Comment: @hjhjhj57 True, but $\approx$ doesn't have a clear definition without context...

Answer (score 3):

Use the classical approximation:
$$\sqrt{a^2 + b} \approx a + \frac{b}{2a}$$
With $a = \sqrt{20}$ and $b = \sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20}}$ we have
$$\sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20}}} \approx \sqrt{20} + \frac{\sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20}}}{2\sqrt{20}} = \sqrt{20} + \frac{\sqrt{400 + 20\sqrt{20}}}{40} $$
Now use the same classical approximation again, this time working with the numerator of the second term.  This time with $a=20$ and $b=20\sqrt{20}$ we get
$$\sqrt{400 + 20\sqrt{20}} \approx 20 + \frac{20\sqrt{20}}{40} = 20 + \frac{\sqrt{20}}{2}$$
Combining these, we've got:
$$\sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20}}} \approx  \sqrt{20} + \frac{20 + \frac{\sqrt{20}}{2}}{40} = \sqrt{20} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{20}}{80}$$

Using similar methods, we get
$$\sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20}}} \approx  \sqrt{20} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{20}}{80}$$

Finally, subtracting one from the other we end up with
$$\sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20}}} -\sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20}}} \approx \left( \sqrt{20} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{20}}{80} \right) - \left( \sqrt{20} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{20}}{80} \right)$$
and in this last expression everything cancels out except for
$$\frac{1}{2} - \left(-\frac{1}{2} \right) = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Repeatedly using
$\sqrt{1+x}
\approx 1+x/2$,

$\begin{array}\\
d(a)
&=\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a}}}\\
&=(\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a}}})\dfrac{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a}}}}{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a}}}}\\
&=\dfrac{(a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}})-(a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a}})}{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a}}}}\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a}}}{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a}}}}\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}(\sqrt{1+1/\sqrt{a}}+\sqrt{1-1/\sqrt{a}})}{\sqrt{a}\sqrt{1+(1/a)\sqrt{a+\sqrt{a}}}+\sqrt{a}\sqrt{1-(1/a)\sqrt{a-\sqrt{a}}}}\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+1/\sqrt{a}}+\sqrt{1-1/\sqrt{a}}}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1/a+1/a^{3/2}}}+\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1/a-1/a^{3/2}}}}\\
&\approx\dfrac{1+1/(2\sqrt{a})+1-1/(2\sqrt{a})} {1+(1/2)\sqrt{1/a+1/a^{3/2}}+1-(1/2)\sqrt{1/a-1/a^{3/2}}}\\
&=\dfrac{2} {2+(1/(2\sqrt{a}))\sqrt{1+1/a}-(1/(2\sqrt{a}))\sqrt{1-1/a}}\\
&\approx\dfrac{2} {2+(1/(2\sqrt{a}))(1+1/(2a)-(1/(2\sqrt{a}))(1-1/(2a)}\\
&\approx\dfrac{2} {2+(1/(2\sqrt{a}))(1/(2a))}\\
&=\dfrac{1} {1+(1/(8a^{3/2}))}\\
&\approx 1-(1/(8a^{3/2}))\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 2):

By binomial formulas and cancellation, you get that
\begin{align}
...&=\frac{\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}+\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}}{\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}}+\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}}}
\\&=\frac{
  \sqrt{5+\sqrt{\frac54}}+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{\frac54}}
  }{
  \sqrt{5+\sqrt{\frac54+\sqrt{\frac5{64}}}}+\sqrt{5-\sqrt{\frac54-\sqrt{\frac5{64}}}}
  }
\end{align}
As one can see, the denominator is a small perturbation of the numerator, so that the quotient will be close to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

As in @mweiss 's answer we use repeatedly the approximation
$$\sqrt{a^2+b}\approx a+{b\over 2a}\qquad(|b|\ll a^2)\ .$$In this way we obtain on the one hand
$$\eqalign{
\sqrt{20}&=\sqrt{25-5}\approx 5-{1\over2},\quad
20+\sqrt{20}\approx25-{1\over2},\cr
\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}&\approx5-{1\over20},\quad 20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}\approx 25-{1\over20},\cr
\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}}&\approx5-{1\over200},
\cr}$$
and on the other hand
$$\eqalign{
\sqrt{20}&=\sqrt{16+4}\approx 4+{1\over2},\quad
20-\sqrt{20}\approx16-{1\over2},\cr
\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}&\approx4-{1\over16},\quad 20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}\approx 16+{1\over16},\cr
\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}}&\approx4+{1\over128}.
\cr}$$
It follos that the quantity $Q$ in question is approximatively given by
$$Q\approx1-{1\over200}-{1\over128}\approx0.9872.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since Alex Meiburg didn't write an answer I'm going to steal his idea:

(Oh, I see he did after all... oh, well, I'm still going to steal his answer.)

$\sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20}}} =$

$\sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20 + \sqrt{25*4/5}}}=$

$\sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20 + 5\sqrt{4/5}}}=$

$\sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20 + 5 +5(\sqrt{4/5}-1)}}=$

$\sqrt{20 + \sqrt{25 +5(\sqrt{4/5}-1)}}=$

$\sqrt{20 + 5\sqrt{1 +(\sqrt{4/5}-1)}}=$

$\sqrt{20 + 5\sqrt[4]{4/5}}=$

$\sqrt{20 + 5 + 5(\sqrt[4]{4/5}-1)}=$

$\sqrt{25 + 5(\sqrt[4]{4/5}-1)}=$

$5\sqrt{1 + (\sqrt[4]{4/5}-1)}=$

$5\sqrt[8]{4/5}\approx 5$ ($\sqrt[8]{4/5}$ = 0.97249247246607303150644442684673)

Likewise

$\sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20}}} =$

$\sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20 - \sqrt{16*5/4}}}=$

$\sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20 - 4\sqrt{5/4}}}=$

$\sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20 - 4 +4(\sqrt{5/4}-1)}}=$

$\sqrt{20 - \sqrt{16 + 4(\sqrt{5/4}-1)}}=$

$\sqrt{20 - 4\sqrt{1 +(\sqrt{5/4}-1)}}=$

$\sqrt{20 - 4\sqrt[4]{5/4}}=$

$\sqrt{20 - 4 + 4(\sqrt[4]{5/4}-1)}=$

$\sqrt{16 + 4(\sqrt[4]{5/4}-1)}=$

$4\sqrt{1 + (\sqrt[4]{5/4}-1)}=$

$4\sqrt[8]{5/4}\approx 4$ (as $\sqrt[8]{5/4}$ = 1.0282855942978896558606746137882)

So $\sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20 + \sqrt{20}}}-\sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20 - \sqrt{20}}}\approx 1$

or precisely $5\sqrt[8]{4/5} - 4\sqrt[8]{5/4} = 1 -5(1- \sqrt[8]{4/5})-  4(\sqrt[8]{5/4}-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some ad hoc evaluation:

$4=\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{16}}} \leq\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}}\leq \sqrt{20-\sqrt{14-\sqrt{25}}}=\sqrt{17}$

$\sqrt{24}\leq\sqrt{20+\sqrt{24}}= \sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{16}}} \leq\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}}\leq \sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{25}}}=5$

And thus, $$1\geq\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}}-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}}\geq \sqrt{24}-\sqrt{17}\approx 0.776$$

This is not that good so let us approximate $\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt {25}}} = \sqrt{20-\sqrt{15}}$ instead by using [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). In this particular case when we want to approximate $\sqrt a$, we want zero of polynomial $x^2-a$ which in turn gives us formula $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2-a}{2x_n}$$
For $\sqrt {15}$ we start with $x_0 = 4$ to get $\sqrt{15} \approx 4-\frac 1 8$ (which for geometric reasons is an overestimate, but actually really close).

So, $\sqrt{20-\sqrt{15}}\approx \sqrt{16+\frac 18}\approx 4- \frac{16-(16+\frac 18)}{8} = 4+ \frac 1{64}$

Similarly, $\sqrt{20+\sqrt {24}}\approx \sqrt{24.9}\approx 4.99$ and our bound becomes $$1\geq\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}}-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}}\geq 4.99-(4+\frac 1{64})\approx 0.9744$$

*Note: The lower bound is no longer true lower bound, but only approximate lower bound, since we overestimated square roots every time we used Newton's method. So, let us have some comparisons:*

$\sqrt {20+\sqrt{24}}\approx 4.99$ (our estimate), while $\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20+\sqrt{20}}}\approx 4.99469$ (computer estimate)

$\sqrt{20-\sqrt{15}}\approx 4.015625$ (our estimate), while $\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20-\sqrt{20}}}\approx 4.00743$ (computer estimate)

And finally, since we have that $0.9744 \leq x \leq 1$, we could take arithmetic mean to get estimate $x\approx 0.9872$, while computer estimates $x\approx 0.9872649$.